# VIE Language Input showed in language input list despite not config from Settings

Tags: windows-10, ime

Sometimes, I got troubles when typing, when I look to the system tray, I see the language input method has been changed to "VIE - Vietnamese keyboard"
the problem is, I didn't ever config it, below is evidences

How could I remove the VIE language from my Language IME list?

[image]

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUY4U.png)]

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to remove this by following the steps below.

1. Press Windows + I keys simultaneously to open the Settings app.
2. Click on "Time & Language."
3. On the left sidebar, click on "Region & language."
4. Under the "Languages" section, you should see a list of languages that have been added.
5. Locate "Tiếng Việt" or similar (that represents Vietnamese).
6. Click on it and then select "Remove."
7. While still in "Time & Language," click on "Language" from the left sidebar.
8. Under "Preferred languages," click on English
9. Click on "Options."
10. Under "Keyboards," check if there's a Vietnamese keyboard. If there is, 11. click on it and then select "Remove."

After you've removed the Vietnamese language and/or keyboard, you should no longer see it in your system tray.

Comment: There is no "vietnamese" or "tiếng việt" in my Language list, here is evidence: https://imgur.com/TePRLlG